# Apply filter to column 1 but include exception is column 2 is below some value

Tags: python, pandas

Sample data:

```
Val1 Val2
1.  10
1.  12
3.  42
3.  14
5.  12
```

So the filtering logic is like this:

1. Remove `Val1` if it is less than 3 Unless `Val2` is less than 11

So, after applying this condition, my dataset would look like this:

```
Val1 Val2
1.  10
3.  42
3.  14
5.  12
```

Is there a concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing rows where `Val1` is less than 3 Unless `Val2` is less than 11, is equal to keeping rows where `Val1` >= 3 or `Val2` < 11:

```
>>> df[(df.Val1 >= 3) | (df.Val2 < 11)]
   Val1  Val2
0     1    10
2     3    42
3     3    14
4     5    12
```

Answer (score 2):

Try comparing both booleans:

```
In [24]: cond1 = df.Val1 < 3

In [25]: cond2 = df.Val2 < 11

df.loc[~(cond1 > cond2)]
Out[29]: 
   Val1  Val2
0   1.0    10
2   3.0    42
3   3.0    14
4   5.0    12
```

It compares both boolean Series; if cond1 is True and cond2 is False, then that row should be dropped, as it does not meet the requirements.